# Area of surface cut off a sphere by a cone

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Find the area of the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ cut off by the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

First of all, I want to set up the integral only on the part of the sphere that lies inside the cone. In order to do that, I need to find the circle of intersection of these two objects.

I am using cylindrical coordinates. 
sphere: $r^2 + z^2 = 4$ 
cone: $z = r$ 
Solving for the radius: $r = \sqrt2$ 
Angle: $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$

And so the area of integration will be:
$$A = \{(r, \theta): 0 \le r \le 2\pi \land 0 \le r \le \sqrt 2 \}$$
And the upper surface can be parametrized as
$$T(r, \theta) = (r, \theta, \sqrt{4-r^2})$$
And now, we only need to set up the surface integral over $A$, remembering about the Jacobian $r$:
$$\iint_A \|\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\|rdrd\theta$$

Is my method correct?

Comment: This is the spirit. However, you should not include the $r$ in the integral before $dr d\theta$. It will appear automatically in the $\|\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\|$ term.

Comment: @Kuifje  I do not understand why the Jacobian will get there "himself". Could you, please, elaborate a little bit more on it?

Comment: This is not substantially different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2820593/265466).

Comment: I wanted to make sure that I got the gist of surface integrals.